# com/ibm/xml/xlxp2/api/wssec/WSSXMLStreamReader cause out of memory issue

Tags: out-of-memory, websphere, system-properties, was, xmlstreamreader

Good day,

2 years ago, my application hit OOME issue, I analyze the heap dump and found that its cause by `com/ibm/xml/xlxp2/api/wssec/WSSXMLStreamReader`, I tried to google around and found this IBM article:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PM42465

Base on what I understand from this article, I need to add in a system property which is call `com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.Pool.STRONG_REFERENCE_POOL_MAXIMUM_SIZE` and set its value to 0.

Thus, I set this in Application Servers > myApp > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom Properties:
[image]

I restart the server and so far didnt see this OOME issue happen again for 2 years. (In fact I am not sure this solution is work or not as I also want to keep in view)

Last week, there is a OOME issue reported again, and I check the `heapdump`, found that its same issue again.
[image]

Looks like add the system property is not work.

May I know who to fix this OOME issue? Is the step I did is correct? My WAS version is 8.5.5.

Kindly advise, appreciate your help.